# How to multiply a list of text by a list of integers and get one long list of text?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

This is for Python 3. I have two lists:

```
lista = ['foo', 'bar']
listb = [2, 3]
```

I'm trying to get:

```
newlist = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

But I'm stuck. If I try:

```
new_list = []
for i in zip(lista, listb):
    new_list.append([i[0]] * i[1])
```

I get:

```
[['foo', 'foo'], ['bar', 'bar', 'bar']]
```

I know that this works, but I won't always know the contents of each list.

```
new_list = ['foo'] * 2 + ['bar'] * 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close yourself! All you needed to do was use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) instead of `list.append`:

```
new_list = []
for i in zip(lista, listb):
    new_list.extend([i[0]] * i[1])
```

this extends the list `new_list` with the elements you supply (appends each individual element) instead of appending the full list.

If you need to get fancy you could always use functions from `itertools` to achieve the same effect:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

new_list = list(chain(*map(repeat, lista, listb)))
```

`.extend` in a loop, though slower, beats the previous in readability.

Comment: Baahh, I knew I was close. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use *list comprehension* with the following *one liner*:

```
new_list = [x for n,x in zip(listb,lista) for _ in range(n)]
```

The code works as follows: first we generate a `zip(listb,lista)` which generates tuples of `(2,'foo'), (3,'bar'), ...` Now for each of these tuples we have a second `for` loop that iterates `n` times (`for _ in range(n)`) and thus we add `x` that many times to the list.

The `_` is a variable that is usually used to denote that the value `_` carries is not important: it is only used because we need a variable in the for loop to force iteration.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the "_" is used for in the for loop?

Comment: The `_` is a variable one usually uses to say the variable itself does not matter. We do not use the loop counter. We only use it for the `for` loop that forces to add the element `n` times.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) rather than `.append()`.